# Numpy histogram output to a file

Tags: python, numpy

I am beginner to python and numpy.

Below is the part of the script I am working on. I am able to output the final values to hist.txt but I want output as a 3D array where the first column is binX and the second column is bin Y and the third column is hist2.

### HISTOGRAM EVERYTHING

```
hist2, newedgesX, newedgesY = np.histogram2d(inputfile[:,0], inputfile[:,1], bins = (binsX, binsY), weights=weights )
cb_max=8  ## MAX VALUE TO SET ALL INFINITY VALUES TOO AND TO SET THE COLORBAR TO
hist2=prephist(hist2, cb_max)
np.savetxt('hist.txt',hist2,delimiter='\n')
cbar_ticks=[0, cb_max*.25, cb_max*.5, cb_max*.75, cb_max]
```

Comment: You'll need to show us some sample input, full working code that runs on that input, and your current vs. desired outputs.

Comment: Does it need to be a text file?

Comment: `hist2` is a N by N 2D array, `newedgesX/Y` are N+1 1D arrays, so you'll have to think if your suggestion about 3 columns next to each other makes sense: the columns won't have equal length, for example. Perhaps you want to save the centers of the bins instead?

Comment: Evert, you are right. The columns i.e. newedges X/Y don't have equal lengths. Is there an alternative solution?